# send http request through GET method

Tags: php, api, http, get

I'm trying to access an API through GET method but each time it returns nothing. Here is the code I tried so far:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.printful.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'get');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($info);
    if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
        print_r(json_decode ($output, true));
    } else {
           print_r(array("error" => array("message" => "ERROR: " . $info['http_code'])));
      }
```

when trying to URL in the browser it will bring the result.

Comment: You can either remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'get');` or make it `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');` to make it work. You should better remove it as by default curl requests are GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request methods need to be uppercase. If you do a GET request, you can even let it away, because it is the default unless you are not using post data.

Remove the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'get');
```

And the output will be

```
Array
(
    [code] => 200
    [result] => Welcome to the Printful API
    [extra] => Array
        (
        )

)
```